# knockout.js bind to static data

Tags: knockout.js

What's the suggested way to bind to existing static data? I have to include this in the viewmodel because its used in computed values.

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/4/

```
<div id="sum" data-bind="text: sum">
</div>
<div class="line">
    dynamic: <span data-bind="text: dynamicValue"></span>
    static: <span data-bind="text: staticValue">312</span>
    <button data-bind="click: getDataFromServer">get data</button>
</div>
<div class="line">
    dynamic: <span data-bind="text: dynamicValue"></span>
    static: <span data-bind="text: staticValue">123</span>
    <button data-bind="click: getDataFromServer">get data</button>
</div>
```

​

```
function SumViewModel(lines){
    this.sum = ko.computed(function(){
        var value = 0;
        $.each(lines, function(index, element){
            var staticValue = element.staticValue();
            if (staticValue)
                value += staticValue;
            var dynamicValue = element.dynamicValue();
            if (dynamicValue)
                value += dynamicValue;
            value += dynamicValue;
        });
        return value;
    });
}

function LineViewModel() {

    this.randomNumber = function(max) {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    };

    this.dynamicValue = ko.observable(0);
    this.staticValue = ko.observable();

    this.getDataFromServer = function() {
        this.dynamicValue(this.randomNumber(300));
    };

};

var lines = [];
$('.line').each(function(index, element) {
    var line = new LineViewModel()
    //line.staticValue(parseInt($('[data-bind*="staticValue"]', element).text()));
    lines.push(line);
    ko.applyBindings(line, element);
});
var sum = new SumViewModel(lines);
ko.applyBindings(sum, $('#sum')[0]);
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at creating a custom binding, which would initialize the staticValue observable.  Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/6/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction! What do you think about this: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/7/

Comment: Okay... if you really want the value to be read from the innerText here are a couple of tweaks.  1) I am now using the string parameter sent to the staticText binding to dynamically set that property on the viewModel. 2) I do the parse inside the binding, instead of the sum. 3) I used jQuery to access the text, as .innerText doesn't work in FireFox. 4) staticValue no longer needs to be an observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/9/

Comment: maybe this is getting out of scope, but how can I make it so that the new binding works with fields aswell as observables?

Comment: If it is needed you could check the type of the staticField.  If it is a function then invoke it as function rather than just setting the value: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/10/

Answer (score 1):

Your view is inefficient, better use the foreach binding to render the lines. If you need data in the viewmodel, it belongs in the viewmodel, or should be fetched from the server. Don't put in the view and extract it back.

```
function SumViewModel(lines) {
    // ...
    this.lines = lines;
}

function LineViewModel(staticValue) {
    // ...
    this.staticValue = ko.observable(staticValue);
}

var staticValues = [312, 123];
var lines = [];

$.each(staticValues, function(index, value) {
    lines.push( new LineViewModel(value) );
});

ko.applyBindings( new SumViewModel(lines) );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2ykC/5/

​

Comment: yes, although I agree that that would be optimal, I dont have that option right now. its by far not the easiest option either.